# Change Zend Framework module view script path

Tags: zend-framework, view, module, path

Currently view scripts located in `APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/my_module/views/scripts/'`. I want to place scripts in `'/modules/my_module/views/'` (remove scripts folder). How to achieve this?

application.ini:

```
resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
resources.modules[] =
resources.view.scriptPath.default = APPLICATION_PATH "/views"
```

Answer (score 6):

You could use the [`setScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/my_module/views')`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/_View_Abstract.html#%5CZend_View_Abstract) view method to replace the script path.

You can also add your script path without overriding the previous one, using [`addScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/modules/my_module/views')`](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/1.11/_View_Abstract.html#%5CZend_View_Abstract). I use it to have organized the view scripts in different folders.

Hope that helps...

Answer (score 1):

if you want change view script for any action
inside your controller action add this:

$this->view->addScriptPath(APPLICATION_PATH . 'your/path');
$this->renderScript('list.phtml');

Answer (score 0):

I know this is pretty old but it may help someone. I had this same problem. I achieved this by using

```
resources.view.scriptPath = APPLICATION_PATH "/views/"
```